# Is it possible to call some of the pallet extrinsics from `on_initialize` hook?

Tags: frame, hook

Probably a dumb question, but is it possible to do something like this?

```rust
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_initialize(now: BlockNumberFor<T>) -> Weight {
        Self::some_extrinsic(origin, now); // what would the origin be here?
        Weight::zero()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a good idea. You can just put the functionality into a new private function and then call that instead. Then you wont need an origin.
If the functionality can be injected then use a trait. Everything in [`frame-support/traits`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/traits/index.html#traits) basically.
For example the [Currency](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.Currency.html) trait which is implemented by other pallets to allow for re-usability without the need to dispatch another call.